# how to open cameraroll automatically after opening app - swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, camera

I'm working on a photo editor app , and I want to open camera-roll automatically when I open my app. I'm using sheet to trigger camera-roll and has a button to make the variable true .  But I want to make it auto.

My code:

```
Zstack{
    Button()//this makes variable true
    }
   ..sheet(isPresented: $openCameraRoll) {
        ImagePicker(pickedImage: $vm.pickedImage , bgRemovedImage : $vm.bgRemovedImage , proActive : $vm.proActive , sourceType: .photoLibrary)
    }
```

Comment: you can change the $openCameraRoll `onAppear()`

Comment: @Yodagama tried this , but not working

Comment: Where does your ImagePicker comes from ? And how are defined its parameters ?

Comment: What happens if you open a different sheet in `onAppear` (or `task()`)? What happens if you insert a little delay before changing `$openCameraRoll` from `false` to `true`?